# Speeding up Titan graph traversals

Tags: titan, gremlin

I have been playing around with a very small graph of **264,346 vertices** and **733,846 edges**. I bulk imported it into Titan using `BatchGraph` and the recommended settings. This worked out fine - it is surprisingly efficient.

I am now playing around with graph traversals and implemented a quick Dijkstra's algorithm in Java using the Java libraries. I should mention I have a local Cassandra node that my Titan database is running on - it is not the embedded one.

An average Dijkstra run takes **1+ minute** for an average path in this graph. This is extremely long. I would expect a **very** slow Dijkstra run on such a graph to take under 10 seconds (with an in-memory graph average queries on this graph size would take well under 1 second).

**What are the best practices for running such algorithms over Titan efficiently?**

I will give parts of the simple Dijkstra implementation in case the way I am accessing vertices and edges is not the most efficient way.

Getting the graph instance:

```
TitanGraph graph = TitanFactory.open("cassandra:localhost");
```

Parts of the Dijkstra implementation (specifically involving graph access):

```
public int run(long src, long trg){
    this.pqueue.add(new PQNode(0, src));
    this.nodeMap.put(src, new NodeInfo(src, 0, -1));
    int dist = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    while (!this.pqueue.isEmpty()){
        PQNode current = this.pqueue.poll();
        NodeInfo nodeInfo = this.nodeMap.get(current.getNodeId());
        long u = nodeInfo.getNodeId();

        if (u == trg) {
            dist = nodeInfo.getDistance();
            break;
        }

        if (nodeInfo.isSeen())
            continue;

        this.expansion++;

        TitanVertex vertex = graph.getVertex(u);
        for (TitanEdge out: vertex.getEdges()){
            Direction dir = out.getDirection(vertex);
            if (dir.compareTo(Direction.OUT) != 0 && dir.compareTo(Direction.BOTH) != 0){
                continue;
            }

            TitanVertex v = out.getOtherVertex(vertex);
            long vId = (long)v.getId();
            NodeInfo vInfo = this.nodeMap.get(vId);
            if (vInfo == null){
                vInfo = new NodeInfo(vId, Integer.MAX_VALUE, -1);
                this.nodeMap.put(vId, vInfo);
            }
            int weight = out.getProperty("weight");
            int currentDistance = nodeInfo.getDistance() + weight;
            if (currentDistance < vInfo.getDistance()){
                vInfo.setParent(u);
                vInfo.setDistance(currentDistance);
                this.pqueue.add(new PQNode(currentDistance, vId));
            }
        }
        nodeInfo.setSeen(true);
    }


    return dist;
}
```

How should I proceed trying to execute such algorithms efficiently over Titan?

Answer (score 0):

Forgetting about your code/algorithm, I have to agree that as you say, your graph is "very small".  That begs the question why you chose to use cassandra as your backend.  For a graph of that size, I would try out berkeleydb to see if that helps.  Or perhaps if you want to go really extreme just use the fastest Blueprints implementation there is: [TinkerGraph](https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki/TinkerGraph)!

As for the code sample itself, one suggestion might be to stop iterating all edges on a vertex if you don't need to:

```
for (TitanEdge out: vertex.getEdges()){
    Direction dir = out.getDirection(vertex);
    if (dir.compareTo(Direction.OUT) != 0 && dir.compareTo(Direction.BOTH) != 0){
            continue;
    }
```

Instead if you just want in" edges tell Titan that: `vertex.getEdges(Direction.IN)`.  That should give you some extra efficiency there - I'd even do that if you decided to just load to TinkerGraph.  That would also eliminate the need for that `getOtherVertex` line because then you know to just `out.getVertex(Direction.OUT)` which I'd guess to be faster.